# Using dynamic data to plot Chart.js but show cant read property "skip" of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to angular js and chart js. I want to plot graph with chart js with dynamic data, here is the result when server return:
[image]

I get the "nameArray" and "values" from the server and want to put inside chart.js

```
 $scope.drawChart = function () {
            console.log("start draw");
            var name = $scope.result.nameArray
            var value = $scope.result.values
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                // The type of chart we want to create
                type: 'bar',

                // The data for our dataset
                data: {
                    labels: name,
                    datasets: [{
//                        label: "My First dataset",
                        label: name,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
//                        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
                        data: value,
                    }]
                },

                // Configuration options go here
                options: {}
            });
        }
```

And my angular controller part:

```
$scope.result = [];
$scope.getPosts = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/test.php',
                data: {
                    "action": "getchartdata",
                    "username": "username",
                    "deptname": "departname",
                    "officename": "office",
                    "softwarename": "this",
                    "StartTime": "time",
                    "EndTime": "time",
                    "ipaddress": "10.0.90.1"
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    var str = [];
                    for (var p in data)
                        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                }
            }).then(function (result) {
                $scope.result = result.data
                console.log($scope.result);
                console.log($scope.result.nameArray)
                $scope.drawChart();
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("error")
            });
        };
```

I get this error:
[image]

I not sure what happening there, or is that chartjs doest support like this?

Comment: Can you parse the two arrays JSON.parse($scope.result.nameArray)
    JSON.parse($scope.result.values) and see if there is any difference?

Comment: @Vivz yes, it works. Once i turn in to JSON.parse, this error is gone, and graph function is working now.

Comment: Yes I knew it that you had to parse :)